# How to map a child Set<UUID> using @ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using UUID as PK for an entity and this entity has a `Set<UUID>` child property mapped using `@ElementCollection`. When persisting the parent entity, I'm getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID`

I have looked at @MapKeyClass, @Column, @CollectionTable, and @JoinColumn annotations but no one offers a way to specify the child Set uses UUID for FK and for its values. My last try was to add this to the attribute `@CollectionTable(name = "test_target_files_ids", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id", referencedColumnName="id", columnDefinition="binary(16) not null"))`

My entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Campaign
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    UUID id;
    String name;
    // more attributes...

    @ElementCollection
    Set<UUID> targetFilesIds; // This is just a list of UUIDs representing external files or any other object, it does not matter
```

I expect the entity and its child UUID list to be persisted but only the entity is persisted. I get this error message

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.UUIDTypeDescriptor.unwrap(UUIDTypeDescriptor.java:20) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:912) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1335) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1483) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:512) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3321) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2517) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:533) ~[spring-orm-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysoftware.service.CampaignService.save(CampaignService.java:83) ~[classes/:na]

(... more lines and no other cause in the stacktrace)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all my fault: I'm receiving a RequestObject (CampaignRequest) through a REST API and then, I use DozerBeanMapper in the REST controller with a custom dozer converter to convert from/to `String` and `UUID`: the API receives UUIDs as strings (in the request) and then Dozer convert them to `java.util.UUID` (to use in the Entity).

In the debugger, I found out that, as per my configuration, DozerMapper converts single properties (ie: id) to and from UUID or String without any problem using my custom converter, however, for set of UUIDs, Dozer maps the Set attribute (coming in the request) to another Set in the Entity.

I really don't know why my entity, which has a strong typed `Set<UUID>` attribute, allows Dozer to set that attribute to another different type (`Set<String>`).

Now I changed my code to manually convert the incoming Set (in the request) to a Set (in the entity) and the error disappeared. It was not a JPA mapping related error, it was a Dozer mapping related issue. This code fixed the problem but I still need to find a way to use Dozer to convert `Set<String>` to `Set<UUID>` (I'm still reading this: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/collectionandarraymapping.html):

```java
if (campaignRequest.getTargetFilesIds() != null)
{
    final HashSet<UUID> ids = new HashSet<>();
    campaignRequest.getTargetFilesIds().forEach(id -> ids.add(UUID.fromString(id)));
    campaign.setTargetFilesIds(ids);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `@CollectionTable` annotation and specify appropriate field names. Something like this: `@CollectionTable(name = "target_files_ids", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))`
The name param in `@CollectionTable` is the name of the table that the info will be stored in.
The name param in `@Joincolumn` is the name of the field on your Campaign entity that will be used to identify the data in `target_files_ids` table.

Take a look at this example to further understand. https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-element-collection-demo/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already tried it and I tried it again after your answer. This is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but I was using list as *@elementcollection*.
Made this to resolve the issue, hope it helps you:

```
@ElementCollection
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = 
"org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@CollectionId(columns = @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, 
nullable = false,columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)"),type = @Type(type = 
"java.util.UUID"), generator = "uuid")
@CollectionTable(name = "country_phone_numbers",joinColumns = 
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id"))
private List<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```